# Change feed reliability for cosmosDB multi region writes

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to use change feed from CosmosDB which has multi region writes. Based on my search, I understand change feed consumers read from a single region. My questions are

1. Does change feed consumer has fail over option if the specific region fails ?
2. In session consistency, is there a maximum time limit for writes to replicate in all regions, in case I try to read the change from another region as failover ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change Feed as an API behaves like any other API of the Cosmos DB service in regards to failover, and it responds to the behavior in https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql/troubleshoot-sdk-availability. So yes, if the region you were reading the Change Feed goes offline, and you are using the official SDKs, they will failover. In the case of multi region writes, if there were some writes in that region that were not propagated yet, they will do so after the region comes back up.
2. No, there is no time limit or documented expected time for propagation (this is unrelated to Change Feed but rather how the system propagates data).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Let's say my Azure function reads change feed from region 1. The lease container in the same region has continuation token 100. Now region 1 went down before propagating the consumed change to region 2. As a failover , change feed azure function now reads from collection & leases in another region. If the leases in this failover region has propagated continuation token till 99, Does the function receives the duplicate change after region 1 comes back up and propagates the missing change ?

Comment: It could receive a duplicated change yes, but duplication is always part of the picture, even when failovers or regional outages do not happen. This is valid for all event-based Triggers in Functions (like Event Hub)

Comment: Well explained. Thanks